# Safari sandboxes iframe after opening the parent page for the second time

Tags: iframe, safari

I have a web page with a single `iframe` in the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="${cross_identifier}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.js"></script>
    <title>${cross_target}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="web_view"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

A JS function sets the `src` of the `iframe`:

```
document.getElementById('web_view').src = 'assets/' + page + '.htm';
```

My app works fine in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome but not in Safari:

1. Open the app, it works fine for the first time. It even works if I refresh the working page.
2. open the app in a new tab or new window, it gives `The frame being accessed is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.` error in the line that sets `src` attribute.
3. Clear history of safari.
4. Open the app again and it works.

Not sure if related, but my project has `wasm` file as well and `cross origin` headers are set like:

- Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy same-origin
- Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy require-corp

for all files.

Setting `Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy same-origin` didn't help.

Setting `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` didn't help.

[Link of my app](https://www.shaidin.com/checkers/online) (hope you enjoy playing)